# What lightbox script does Jezebel (Gawker Media) use?

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox

Example here: http://jezebel.com/5896408/racist-hunger-games-fans-dont-care-how-much-money-the-movie-made

Click on the 3x3 Tweets screencap they have up. I love the way the lightbox makes a scrollbar. I viewed the source and inspected the element via Chrome and don't see any script that stands out, so I'm guessing it's probably something custom-made.

If so, does anyone know of similar scripts that look like that lightbox and can have a scrollbar effect like that? It's gorgeous!

**Edit:** I found the code, and I do not think they use a modified version of lytebox: http://ganja.gawkerassets.com/assets/base.v10/static/base.v10.jqueryplugin.20120424_8.js (ctrl/cmd + f for 'glimage'. They use their own thing. Still, I am having trouble finding the perfect jQuery lightbox with presentable vertical scrolling if the image is larger than the windowWidth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that they're using a modified version (glytebox) of this script:
http://lytebox.com/

IMHO, their lightbox isn't anything special. The scrollbar is probably something that most lightboxes display when the content is too big to fit on the screen.

Comment: I've used dozens of lightbox scripts and I have not encountered a lightbox script like that. And thanks, I will check into it!

Comment: I found the code, and I do not think they use a modified version of lightbox. They use their own thing. Still, I am having trouble finding the perfect jQuery lightbox with presentable vertical scrolling if the image is larger than the windowWidth.